# Is there a way for tasklist on windows to read variables made by set?

Tags: batch-file, tasklist

I'm trying create a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) which checks if my `mysql server` is up and running before running other stuff. I'm trying to do this by reading the `.pid` file, (`set` to a variable, `%pid%`), then ask [tasklist](/questions/tagged/tasklist) check for it.

The problem is that `tasklist` doesn't seem to like the `%` sign, so it's a bit hard to do this. Every time I try do to this I get:

> `ERROR: The search filter cannot be recognized.`

I don't think you can read variables any other way but I'm relatively new to batch scripting so I may be wrong.

Heres a copy of the script:

```
set pid=C:\mysql\data\DESKTOP-MG3L38L.pid
rem making sure the pid var exists
type %pid%
tasklist /fi 'pid eq %pid%
```

Comment: Yes, i have exactly the same problem!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your real issue is that you're not `Set`ting your variable to the content of the first line of your file; you're `Set`ting it to the name of the file.

To set it to the content of the first line of the file you would use:

```bat
@Set /P "PID="<"C:\mysql\data\DESKTOP-MG3L38L.pid"
```

Because you're not setting it correctly `TaskList` is trying to filter the name of the file, `C:\mysql\data\DESKTOP-MG3L38L.pid` as the numeric integer sequence, which will obviously fail.

Once, you've fixed that, you can run your `TaskList` command:

```bat
@TaskList /Fi "PID Eq %PID%" /Fi "Status Eq Running"
```

Comment: I thought tasklist would read the file like type did for some reason. Apparently not.